# Android RecyclerView Get child item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have one `RecyclerView` in my `Activity`. Each Rows have a `Button`.
how can i get witch button clicked and do something.
means:

if row #1 clicked on button shows "a"

if row #2 clicked on button shows "b";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem and there are undoubtedly many solutions to it. This is the one I found is the most versatile:

The way this method works is by registering your adapter as a listener to view events in your ViewHolder objects:

**Step 1:**
Create a new interface class:

```
public interface MyCardListener {
    boolean buttonPressed(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent, int position);
}
```

**Step 2:**
Modify your ViewHolder class to pass the motionevent and data position to the listener when the button is pressed:

```
public class MyCardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Button actionBtn;

    public MyCardViewHolder(View itemView) {...}

    public void setListener(final MyCardListener listener, final int position){
        actionBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent){
                return listener.buttonPressed(view, motionEvent, position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**
Modify your `Adapter` to receive the button events:

```
public class MyCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCardViewHolder> implements MyCardListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyCardViewHolder holder, int position){
        ...
        holder.setListener(this, position)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean buttonPressed(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent, int pos){
        //the button on the card at position pos was pressed
    }
}
```

Once you have the position, you know which card was pressed :)